# service returning always the value set in the constructor

Tags: angular, angular5

I am developing a game just for fun and to learn Angular v5. In a service I created, I set a default value in the constructor, have a getter and a setter. While running the project in debug mode I notice that:

- The debugger never stops at the constructor
- The setter is called and the selectedBoat is set to a different value than the one from the constructor
- The getter returns always the value set in the constructor.
- The service is being injected in 2 components, one I  call the setter and in the other the getter.

The service code is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BoatType } from '../../shared/modules/boatType';

@Injectable()
export class BoatContainerService {
  private boats: number[] = [BoatType.AircraftCarrier, BoatType.Battleship, BoatType.Destroyer, BoatType.PatrolBoat, BoatType.Submarine];
  private selectedBoat: BoatType;

  constructor() { 
    this.selectedBoat = BoatType.Undefined;
  }

  selectBoat(boat: BoatType) {
    this.selectedBoat = boat;
  }

  ignoreSelection() {
    this.selectedBoat = BoatType.Undefined;
  }

  removeBoat(boat: BoatType) {    
    this.boats.slice(boat, boat + 1);
  }

  getSelected() : BoatType {
    return this.selectedBoat;
  }
}
```

BoatType is an enum:

```
export enum BoatType {
    Undefined = 1,
    AircraftCarrier,
    Battleship,
    Destroyer,
    Submarine,
    PatrolBoat
}
```

I tried to replace the data type to a number and the behavior is the same.

So, basically it is not working because even when I call the selectBoat(...), the getSelected() returns always "Undefined". Why?

Comment: Is the service present only in one `providers` list? In other words, is there only one instance of your service in the application? If the two components are in the same module, the service should be in the `providers` of the module.

Comment: No, I am declaring it in a Component and in a Directive.

Comment: Make sure that it is in only one list of `providers`.

Comment: ok, I got that from your previous comment. My question is how inject a service in 2 Components, I need it in both sides.

Comment: You inject the service in the constructor of each component. You can inject it in several places, but it should be provided only once.

Comment: @Bonomi can you give me a feedback why my answer is working or not for you ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps of add the service to provider list and injected:

add the service to module provider

```
import { BoatContainerService } from './boat-container.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [BoatContainerService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

inject ther service to component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {BoatContainerService} from './boat-container.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor (public BoatContainer:BoatContainerService) { 

  }
}
```

> Add the service to single module(AppModule) will make the service `singleton` or `shared service` so will persist the state of the service and will create only once.

In Angular 6 you can skip add the service to app.module by setup this in service `Injectable` decorator

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BoatContainerService {
  ...
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-inject)